# rails 5 scope has_many through distinct and where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Is it possible to use both `distinct` and `where` in a rails scope?

```
# this works
has_many: specialties, -> { distinct }, through: :doctor_specialties

# this also works
has_many: specialties, -> { where "name != 'Jeff'" }, through: :doctor_specialties
```

Is it possible to combine them into one scope?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, the `scope` argument to `has_many` is just something that returns a relation so you could say:

```
has_many :specialties, -> { distinct.where("name != 'Jeff'") }, ...
```

or

```
has_many :specialties, -> { where("name != 'Jeff'").distinct }, ...
```

if you wish.

Keep in mind that scope will have access to the `specialties` and `doctor_specialties` tables so that `name` would probably be referencing `specialties.name`. Perhaps Jeff is a high maintenance patient that requires years of special training to treat him.

Also, you might want to rewrite that `where("name != 'Jeff'")` like this:

```
where.not(specialties: { name: 'Jeff' })
```

to disambiguate the `name` reference by explicitly tying it to `specialties` and use a broken out query rather than an SQL snippet.